# Personalization is not working in Layout Service call?

Tags: jss, layout-service

I only installed `Sitecore JavaScript Services Server for Sitecore 9.1.1 XP 11.1.0 rev. 190508.zip` to check Layout Services and nothing else.

My jss layout service is absolutely working fine with url

`http://sc91.local/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={key}`

from the browser and Postman. I got the response as below.

```
{"sitecore":{"context":{"pageEditing":false,"user":{"domain":"sitecore","name":"admin"},"site":{"name":"website"},"pageState":"preview","language":"en"},"route":{"name":"Copy of Home","displayName":"Copy of Home","fields":{"Text":{"value":"<p>For further information, please go to the <a rel=\"noopener noreferrer\" href=\"https://doc.sitecore.net/\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Sitecore Documentation site\">Sitecore Documentation site</a></p>"},"Title":{"value":"Copy of Home Sitecore Experience Platform"}},"databaseName":"master","deviceId":"fe5d7fdf-89c0-4d99-9aa3-b5fbd009c9f3","itemId":"b34735c1-ae9c-4098-92d9-74868859daac","itemLanguage":"en","itemVersion":1,"layoutId":"14030e9f-ce92-49c6-ad87-7d49b50e42ea","templateId":"76036f5e-cbce-46d1-af0a-4143f9b557aa","templateName":"Sample Item","placeholders":{}}}}
```

When i add personalization rule to the item, i didn't find any change in response.

I added tracking=true as well but no change. i.e. `http://sc91.local/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={key}&tracking=true`

i got `visitorIdentificationTimestamp":637088102292400969` value in the response but no change into the field values.

There is nothing special in the rule. i configured it for **"where true (actions always execute)"** and changed the datasource or just hide the component itself.

Ideally it should return the changed datasource content but it is returning the original content only.

**Note: It includes only those fields that are into the context item and not what datasource items have. Even i don't find any placeholder in the response.**

Edit 1:

Sitecore 9.1 Update 1

License: xDB enabled

xDB settings: Default/No Change

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What you're not telling us are the details we need to know. Is it an XM or XP install? Is your license enabled for xDB?   What are the xDB related settings for tracking?

Comment: Added environment deatils

Comment: Any answer to this? We are having similar issues with the Layout Service response not changing based on any defined personalization rules.